# SELECT row per user with latest time for the day

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am able to get data from DB that I need, except that I only want one row for each date, so for example in the picture below there should be only the second row not the first. I somehow need to be able to get just one row for one user from one date.

```
SELECT id_user, date_created || ' ' || time_created as placed
            FROM (
                        SELECT
                        b_objednavky.uzivatel AS id_uzivatele,
                        b_objednavky.vytvoreno::date AS date_created,
                        to_char(b_objednavky.vytvoreno, 'HH24:MI:SS') as time_created,
                        b_objednavky.created

                    FROM b_objednavky
                    INNER JOIN u_uzivatele ON b_objednavky.uzivatel = (
                     SELECT u_uzivatele.id from u_uzivatele JOIN bw_paid_orders
                           ON u_uzivatele.id = bw_paid_orders.user_id 
                     WHERE bw_paid_orders.active_thru < NOW() + interval '6 months'
                     ) uzivatele
                    INNER JOIN bc_stavy_objednavky ON b_objednavky.stav = bc_stavy_objednavky.id

                    WHERE bc_stavy_objednavky.sysid = 'nova' AND b_objednavky.vytvoreno <= NOW()
                    AND bc_staty.kod NOT IN (
                      'BR', 'CL', 'AR', 'MX'
                    )

                ) AS order
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                  SELECT user_id, max(paid) as last_paid FROM bw_paid_orders
                GROUP BY user_id
                ) last_paid_by_user ON (id_user = user_id) 
                WHERE (created > last_paid OR last_paid IS NULL) AND created BETWEEN ('2017-02' || '-01')::date
            AND ('2017-02' || '-01')::DATE + '1 month'::interval 
            ORDER BY datum_objednani DESC, objednavajici, nazev, duration
```

Comment: Put into a CTE  by using Row_Number Over(Partition By whatever reference u are using ) and select from that CTE where rownumber = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`

> to get just one row for one user from one date

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_user, date_created) ...
```

To get the row with the latest time for the day, add (at the same query level):

```
ORDER BY id_user, date_created, time_created DESC NULLS LAST
```

Details:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: And where should I use it ? in which clause ? I am kind of lost on that

Comment: @jemcaj: in the `select` right at the start, just like Erwin showed

Comment: @jemcaj: Did you follow the link?

Comment: It throws error pointing at `as` before placed, If I put It only at `date_created` then it would not consider time because in that variable there is only date or no ? .. @ErwinBrandstetter I looked at It, but I don't think that I understand what it does

Comment: @jemcaj: Why consider the time to `get just one row for one user from one date`? The only question remaining: *which* row do you want to get per `(id_user, date_created)` if there are more than one. The answer ... is in the linked answer.

Comment: Okay so `DISTINCT ON` will only return unique resuts that I understand. But If I try to use it I get error `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON(id_user...`

Comment: @jemcaj: I added a working `ORDER BY` above. The explanation is ... in the linked answer. If you need a different order in the result, encapsulate in a subquery and order differently in the outer query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you ! After 15 hours it's finally working !

Comment: @jemcaj: Ah, the relief! We've all been there. I can feel it :)